# The fastest way to transfer 'string' from one PYTHON program to another (on one computer)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please give me an advice.
I have two programs. They open in two different windows.
When I get an `input()` in the first, I would need it transfers this `input()` to the second to a ready, empty variable for that, for example `info = ''`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can't just do the work for you. We can only help you with your code. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Put it in a text file.
Edit: When you're done running both programs, delete it after.

Comment: Thank you Mike Tung and sorry for this. I understand. I Just thought it have one line decision. :)

Comment: KudoMD. Thanks! It can work. I appreciate.

Comment: @mynameisalexey glad to hear it. If you get the chance please take a sec to accept my answer as it will give us both reputation points :)

Comment: Do they need to be two different programs? Can you not restructure and just import one within the other?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: The fastest way is very platform dependent, because the word "process" means slightly different things on different platforms.

Comment: Also, strings are immutable in Python. Pre-setting a string to an empty value does not help you in any way.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, you can do this:

```
first.py ----------------------------------------------------
with open("temp.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(input("Enter the variable: "))

second.py ----------------------------------------------
import os
with open("temp.txt") as f:
    info = f.read()
os.remove("temp.txt")
```

So in the first program you are putting the variable into the text file. Then, after the data is saved in `info` variable, delete it.

Edit:
The `open()` statement will be different depending on where the programs are. If they are in the same folder, you can do it as shown. If not, you should read about how to correctly include the full file path.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess it is a not the fastest way but it indeed will work! I appreciate.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work if it is 2 separate programs - what happens when the second program tries to access the file before the first one has written it?

Comment: @Mortz depends on the implementation. I'm assuming this is for OP's personal use, so that scenario is out of scope. If not, OP would just add an exception to deliver an error to the user like `File not found. Did you run first.py?` edit: specifically what would happen is that `second.py` would just error out. Not the end of the world.

Comment: @Mortz, I think It is possible to write the second part of that in while loop and check it until the file is not empty. After that erase information in the file.

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete the file while it's still open?

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mmap.html ?
You can use memory mapped files to share data between different processes.
Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file#Common_uses to see uses. 
Read http://archive.oreilly.com/oreillyschool/courses/Python4/Python4-15.html (A Memory-Mapped Example section) for a detailed example.