# how do I send input, variable and text, from one python script to another python script which is already running?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Windows 10,
I have two python scripts open and running.  I'd like to essentially trick the second python script into thinking it's receiving user input from the first python script.

Linux example: os.system('screen -S scriptnickname variable')
where variable is the input.  I don't now how to do this in windows 10.

Comment: Can't you just make a temporary file to write your data to with the first script. And read it from the second?

Comment: This could help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780376/the-fastest-way-to-transfer-string-from-one-python-program-to-another-on-one/53780483#comment94412483_53780483

Comment: Use any [Inter-process-communication method supported by your OS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication#Approaches).

Comment: thanks all!!  merry xmas eve